# How to iterate the number of arguments in a for loop?

Tags: bash, for-loop, sh

I'm new to bash programming, and I'm trying to implement a for loop that iterates the number of arguments. I tried with "$#" or just "for i", and it didn't work. So, basically, I'm seeking guidance and a way to solve that issue. This is when I execute my script:

```
./cat.sh food.sh house.sh tv.sh
```

In my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in $@
do
echo $i
done
```

I want to echo

```
1
2
3
```

and not

```
food.sh
house.sh
tv.sh
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep a running counter outside of the for loop to iterate over the count of arguments.

This should work:

```
#!/bin/bash

counter=0

for i in "$@"
do
counter=$((counter+1))
echo $counter
done
```

---

Input:

`./cat.sh food.sh house.sh tv.sh`

Output:

```
1
2
3
```

---

Input:

`./cat.sh a b c d e f g`

Output:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the seq binary to be available and taking only the end goal into consideration, one could write something like this.

```
#!/bin/bash
 
seq $#
```

I wouldn't personally go for this solution unless I am in for code golf and would rather stick with already posted pure bash solutions.

Answer (score 1):

`$#` contains the number of arguments so one idea OP could use to write the `for` loop:

```
for ((i=1; i<=$#; i++))
do
    echo $i
done

# or

count=$#

for ((i=1; i<=count; i++))
do
    echo $i
done
```

Answer (score 0):

As the question is tagged `sh`, here's a POSIX-compliant solution (for when you can't assume the existence of either `seq` or the C-style `for` loop):

```
i=1
while [ "$i" -le "$#" ]; do
    printf '%s\n' "$i"
    i=$((i+1))
done
```